# WPML and custom post types archive template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wpml

I am using WPML 3.0.2-a with WordPress 3.8.1

I have a custom post type defined like this:

```
function add_custom_posts(){
    $args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Showcases' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Showcases' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Showcase'),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Showcases' ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View Showcase' ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search Showcases' ),
                    'not_found' => __( 'No Showcases found.' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Showcases found in Trash.' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => 'case-studies',
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'case-studies', 'with_front' => false),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
        );

    register_post_type('showcases', $args);

}

add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_posts', 100 );
```

Visiting a custom post type archive and single post URLs for default language works fine. For example:

```
/case-studies/ 
/case-studies/%postname%/
```

are working perfectly and displaying what they should.

However, it doesn't work for the other language:

```
/de/case-studies/ 
/de/case-studies/%postname%/
```

are both displaying **index.php** template of the WordPress theme. It is actualy 404 page but since we don't have 404.php, index.php is used.

Showcases post type is made translatable in WPML settings.

Do you know why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was the problem.

The string was not translated under WPML -> String translations

When I translated it (case-studies -> de/case-studies) it worked.

Actually, it worked in all variants - both my original code, and code suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this support thread](http://wpml.org/forums/topic/cpt-archive-page-slug/) where they say that one should change the following line (in your code):

```
'has_archive' => 'case-studies',
```

to:

```
'has_archive' => icl_translate('wpml_custom', 'wpml_custom_showcases', 'case-studies'),
```

Might be a good idea to ask the official support for this, as it's commercial software and no documentation is available.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. :( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Works perfectly! Make sure your parameter matches the one in `register_post_type` -- probably why this didn't work for Aleksandar. It should  have been 'showcases', not 'case-studies'.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you, just missing some action :)

`'has_archive' => 'case-studies',`

to

`'has_archive' => icl_translate('wpml_custom', 'wpml_custom_showcases', 'case-studies'),`

THEN

Go to Settings > Permalinks and hit 'Save'.

Let me know if this works perfectly.

Cheers!

Comment: How about take a look at this thread : http://wpml.org/forums/topic/translating-slug-for-a-custom-post-type-which-have-a-variable-slug/ and use the rewrite for slug instead. Let me know if this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
'has_archive' => true
```

?

Should work as desired, if I understood correctly.

Comment: No, doesn't help. Must be something else.